# Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-sql 3.0.2 with spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0 along with java8 in my spark-project.

**While writing to cassandra table I am facing below error**

> latest exception was
> Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at
> consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged
> the write)
>
> Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information
> at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.$anonfun$close$2(TableWriter.scala:282)
> at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)   at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.AsyncStatementWriter.close(TableWriter.scala:277)
> at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraDriverDataWriter.commit(CasssandraDriverDataWriterFactory.scala:46)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$7(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:450)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)    Suppressed:
> java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to
> **kspace.table_cassandra**

**I am using below configuration**

```
concurrentWrites: 2056 #1024 #64
outputBatchSizeBytes: 2048
outputBatchGroupingKey: partition
outputConsistencyLevel: LOCAL_ONE
outputBatchGroupingBufferSize: 3000
outputThroughput_mb_per_sec: 1024 #256
connectionKeep_alive_ms: 30000
readTimeout_ms: 600000
ignoreNulls: true
readConsistencyLevel: LOCAL_ONE
```

Comment: do you explicitly set `spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level` to `LOCAL_ONE` in your configuration?

Comment: @Alex Ott Hi Alex , hope you are doing good. YES I tried with LOCAL_QUAROM its giving error so I changed it to LOCAL_ONE still getting same error.

Comment: @AlexOtt updated question with configurations i am using

Answer (score 1):

Write timeouts happen because your cluster is under-sized and cannot keep up with writes.

You will need to throttle the load from your Spark app as Alex Ott advised so it doesn't overload your cluster. Alternatively, you should consider increasing the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes. Cheers!

Comment: which cluster you are talking about ? my yarn cluster or cassandra cluster ?

Comment: Cassandra cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because Spark Cassandra Connector is trying to write data as fast as possible, and often it overloads individual Cassandra nodes, so they are becoming not responsive (maybe because of Java GC, compaction, etc.).

You can tune [write configuration parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters), like, decreasing `spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes`, `spark.cassandra.output.throughputMBPerSec`, etc., but very often it could be fixed by not using `LOCAL_ONE` consistency level (`spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level`), but `TWO`, or `LOCAL_QUORUM`.

Your configuration is basically pushed nodes to the limit

Comment: Thanks Alex let me tweak it , same configuration i am using to write to another table its working fine , that has less records its seems for this i have 15,781,030 records

Comment: Most probably the compaction kicks in or GC, so the nodes aren’t reachable. Really, just try to use default configuration without tweaking

Comment: where i get default configuration ?

Comment: just remove your customizations, and you'll get default configuration